# Certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051) Python

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

I am trying to connect to a websocket and even though I have updated the certificates, I still cannot connect to the websocket:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user  certifi
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /Users/t**/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (2020.4.5.1)
```

This is the code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import websockets
from websockets import WebSocketClientProtocol

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


async def consumer_handler(websocket: WebSocketClientProtocol) -> None:
    async for message in websocket:
        log_message(message)


async def consume(hostname: str) -> None:
    websocket_resource_url = f'wss://{hostname}'
    async with websockets.connect(websocket_resource_url) as websocket:
        await consumer_handler(websocket)


def log_message(message: str) -> None:
    logging.info(f'Message: {message}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(consume(hostname='echo.websocket.org'))
```

That is the last part of the return:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you have the complete certificate chain?  It’s possible you’re missing an intermediate certificate.

Comment: How can I do the complete chain?

Comment: Concatenate the domain certificate with any intermediate certificates followed by the root certificate.

Comment: Is there a tutorial how to do that?

Comment: That depends on your certificates. In my experience I simply used cat, but order is important here depending on your situation. Here’s a pretty in depth guide I found. Hope it helps. 
https://medium.com/@superseb/get-your-certificate-chain-right-4b117a9c0fce

Comment: To be honest, it looks too complicated for my amateur level. Is there a simpler way? Maybe to clean uninstall and install the certificates?

Comment: Sorry I may have misunderstood the issue here.  Your code is running OK on my machine.  Can you try upgrading websockets?

Comment: I managed to overcome the issue by just reassigning a new virtual environment to the interpreter of the project in PyCharm. Don't know why this worked though...